# how to migrate a question?

Tags: support, migration

How do I migrate a question?  The FAQ doesn't mention that.  I don't even know if there are manuals somewhere.

Comment: Some meta.SO threads that seem to be relevant: [How to Migrate a Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question),
[How to migrate question to programmers.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-to-migrate-question-to-programmers-stackexchange-com) and
[Closing/Migrating question instructions/guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/closing-migrating-question-instructions-guidance). In particular, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91397/183484) is nice - it provides screenshots and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

It's an option you can vote on when you close a question as off-topic. You only get a few options, though. Moderators can migrate to any other site in the SE network, so usually you should flag a moderator for migrations you can't vote on yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It should be presented as an option when you vote to close as off-topic.